# document.getElementById{} is returning null

Tags: javascript, html

`const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel_id");`

i am trying to access carousel by this line  but i am getting an error that carousel is null. i am pasting the relevant code below. this is the error that i am getting

```
main.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at slideVideo (main.js:96:11)
    at HTMLElement.onclick (index.html:1:1)
```

this is the html code that I am using

```
<section class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left button" id="prev"></i>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel_id">
        <video src="../../assests/images/AI Assistant Police-website.mov" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/AI Legal assisstant.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/ai-health.mov" autoplay muted loop controls  controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/arab-lady.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/arab-men.mp4 human - Trim.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/cafe.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/digital human - Trim.mp4 human - Trim.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls  controlsList="nodownload"></video>
        <video src="../../assests/images/edited.mp4" autoplay muted loop controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
    </div>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right button" id="next" onclick="slideVideo()"></i>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="../../main.js" ></script>
```

Below is the javascript code that I am using

```
function toggleVideoSection(showVideo) {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  wrapper.style.display = showVideo ? "flex" : "none";
}
let videoIndex = 0;
videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel_id");

function slideVideo() {
 videoIndex = videoIndex === videos.length ? 0 : videoIndex < 0 ? videos.length - 1 : videoIndex;
 carousel.style.transform = `translate(-${videoIndex * 100}%)`;
 console.log("hello")
};
const updateClick = (e) => {
 videoIndex += e.target.id === "next" ? 1 : -1;
 slideVideo(videoIndex);
};
buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", updateClick));
```

i am trying to access the carousel but its not working

Comment: Are you sure you have the `<script>` tag is after the `<section>` like you show? This is the error you'd get if the script were at the top instead of the bottom.

Comment: Have you try with querySelector ?

Comment: @Barmar i have used <script> tag after the section even though i am facing the same issue

Comment: @RomeoTatchemo yes in tried using querySelector also but nothing is working

Comment: try to add an unique class name ton your div element and do a querySelector on it `<div class="carousel carousel_id" id="carousel_id">` and `querySelector(".carousel_id")`

Answer (score 1):

Add ***defer*** attribute to your script tag. Defer makes sure that your script loads after your html elements. Your script could be loading before the carousel element and that could be the reason why you're not able to get the element.

```html
<script src="../../main.js" defer></script>
```

I copy-pasted your code into code pen and it didn't show the error that you're getting, then i tried copying it into visual studio code and on my local server it also didn't show the error that you're getting.

Comment: before it was same script as you have mentioned but it is showing me the same error   main.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at slideVideo (main.js:96:11)
    at HTMLElement.onclick (index.html:1:1)

Comment: This shouldn't be needed if the script tag is after the element it's trying to select.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to wrap your JS code with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

// JS code here.

});
```

Which will ensure your DOM elements are on page before running JS. This will also allow you to pick and choose which JS to run after DOM is loaded.

OR

Place your  tags just before the closing body tag.

```
<html>
  <body>
    HTML_HERE
    <script src=".."></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have wrap my JS code in DOM but its showing  functions are not defined after defining functions also its saying cannot read null properties

Comment: This isn't needed if the script is after the element.